# Flutter - Bottom bar with different number of screens

Tags: flutter, navigation

an app should be controlled via three navigation points in the foot.
The first point is just one side. The second point consists of a PageView.
In the third point, a list (navigation bar) should be scrolled through and offer many screens.
Is it technically easy to do? I successfully implemented the first and second point.
I still fail on the third point. I want to ask if there is a simple approach to this that I may be overlooking.
My code seems to be going messie: /

It should also be possible, for example, to insert a button in the first "single screen" that references a specific page of the "bottom app bar".[image]

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

Flutter curved navigation bar plugin you can create flutter custom bottom navigation bar in your project.

[link 1](https://rockscoder.com/flutter-tutorial-animated-curved-navigation-bar-package/)

[link 2](https://newbycoder.com/flutter/curved_navigation)

[image]